# Data not inserted in the collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, collections

I am trying to insert document in a collection. The structure of the document looks like this:

```
 [{
 "observationNum" : 1231,
    "observation_data": [{
        "child_id": 1234,
        "child_observation_data": [{
             "activity_performed": true,
             "observation_date": 15062016,
             "teacher_id": 6789
        }]
    }]

 }]
```

To achieve this, I have created 3 models. A Model named `child_observation_data` containing it's data as shown in the JSON structure above. Another Model named `observation_data` containing child_id and child_observation_data. I am trying to insert the data in the collection as shown below however the data isn't inserted in the observation_data model and child_observation_data model. What am I doing wrong?

```
function insertData() {
    var childObservationDataModelObject = ChildObservationData.ChildObservationData({"activity_performed": true, "observation_date": "17May2016", "teacher_id":789});
    var observationDataModelObject = ObservationData.ObservationData({"child_id" : 21386, "child_observation_data":childObservationDataModelObject});
    var activityModelObject = new ActivityModel({"observationNumber" : 123456, "observation_data": observationDataModelObject});

   activityModelObject.save(function(err, savedObject) {
        if(err) {
            console.error("error in saving:", err);
            return;
        }

        if(savedObject != null)
            console.log("Data saved ", savedObject);
    });

    ObservationData.getObservationDataModel()
        .findOne({"child_id" : 21386})
        .populate('child_observation_data')
        .exec(function (err, activity) {
            if (err)
                console.log("error in finding", err);
            console.log('The creator is ', activity);
        });
}
```

The console logs are:

```
Data saved  { observation_data: [ 57eb905265ddc958133ac649 ],
  _id: 57eb905265ddc958133ac64a,
  observationNumber: 123456,
  __v: 0 }
The creator is  null
```

Comment: Are you using mongoose ? Where is the getObservationDataModel function ?

Comment: It returns the OservationModel object that;s created in a separate class.